# How to get array results into a string and echo them out

Tags: php, api

I am very sorry if this is really obvious how ever I am really struggling to get this to work.

I call the url as follows:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$postcode1&destinations=$postcode2&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false&key=MY-KEY";
```

I have the following return array:

```
Array
(
    [destination_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Addres_1
        )

    [origin_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Address_2
        )

    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [elements] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [distance] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => 18.9 km
                                            [value] => 18862
                                        )

                                    [duration] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => 20 mins
                                            [value] => 1184
                                        )

                                    [status] => OK
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => OK
)
```

I am trying to get the distance in a string as follows and the echo it out

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($data, true);
$distance = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']['value'];
```

and the `echo $distance` this echo's out `1` where it should be `18862`

any help welcome

Comment: $distance = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];

Comment: `['distance']['text']['value']` does not exist. "text" does not have any properties under it. "value" is a _sibling_ of "text", not a child of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `['text']` from the:

```
$distance = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']['value'];
```

Making it:

```
$distance = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
```

`text` isn't a parent of `value`